# MySQL @grouping results by ID and sorting them by score" issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a following db format set up:

```
id  fid     name    time    flag
1   224     Mike    112     3
2   555     John    98      5
3   224     Mike    101     0
4   121     Ann     80      1
5   224     Mike    55      7
6   121     Ann     150     4
```

I used following query to sort and display them grouped by fid (or name) and to sort them by lowest time:

```
SELECT id, fid, name, MIN(time), flag FROM dblist GROUP BY name ORDER BY MIN(time)
```

This works fine as I get the output in order I want. Something like:

```
name    time
Mike    55
Ann     80
John    98
```

However, if I try to display fid, flag, or any other fields that are associated with that particular time record I get some other values (presumably first that query comes across).

What I would like to get is following format:

```
id  fid     name    time    flag
5   224     Mike    55      7
4   121     Ann     80      1
2   555     John    98      5
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get this done with just one database and some other query syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: This is because of the way MySQL handles grouping, all the other data is from the first record found, I recommend joining on name and the min time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join on two conditions 1 with name and with the minimum of time score for each name,group by results are indeterminate their order is not guaranteed with the latest or the first record in group

```
select t.* from t
join (SELECT name, MIN(`time`) `time`
 FROM t GROUP BY name) t1
on(t.name = t1.name and t.`time`=t1.`time`)
order by t.`time`
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc02af/6)

Comment: Must be warn that when two records has the same minimal value for the same name the output of this query will show both.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. This seemed like best solution for me, after I changed database name.

Comment: @LuisSiquot Sorry for necromancy here, but what would be the best way to avoid showing duplicate entries if the same minimal value for the same name is found?

Answer (score 1):

use this request

```
SELECT
    id,
    fid, 
    name, 
    MIN(time), 
    flag 
FROM 
    dblist 
GROUP BY
    id, 
    fid, 
    name 
ORDER BY 
    MIN(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc02af/16)**

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.fid, 
       t.name, 
       t.time, 
       t.flag
FROM t t
  LEFT JOIN t t1
    ON t.fid = t1.fid
    AND t.time > t1.time
WHERE t1.time is null
```

Result:

```
| ID | FID | NAME | TIME | FLAG |
|----|-----|------|------|------|
|  2 | 555 | John |   98 |    5 |
|  4 | 121 |  Ann |   80 |    1 |
|  5 | 224 | Mike |   55 |    7 |
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent example as well. Just what I wanted.